What are the consequences of giving honest feedback?
I feel an obligation to help others.
It is painful,but I speak the truth.
I volunteer at an animal shelter and at a food bank.
You can choose to try to ban me.

Perhaps this question and answer extend what you are trying to say: https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/12113/57576 Btw your comments about your volunteer work and banning do not really belong in your question...

The short answer is: A honest response.
So here I go:
All of us here on Ask Ubuntu are volunteers (like you are) and are here to help others. None of the users here are on a mission to ban anyone. Everyone here must abide by the Code of Conduct. As long as you don't step outside those bounds, You have no reason to worry about being banned.
Having said that, May I suggest you read participate in meta and stick to the subjects listed there.

I read the material. What does this refer to "to provide feedback." I try not to take things personal and that people forget and sometimes get confused.

@AndrewK To provide feedback on new ideas or features, or discussing policies that affect the whole network, like this question
